# JavaFX setIconified(false) does not display window

Tags: javafx, jax-rs, jetty

I have a situation in which I have a JavaFX application that allows the primary stage to be iconified by a set of REST endpoints.  Here's the application code:

```
public class server extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Hello.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

    primaryStage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Server jettyServer = new Server(65534);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(jettyServer, "/");
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(
            new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bind(primaryStage).to(Stage.class);
                }
            }
    );
    rc.packages("com.cognivue.jettypoc.rest");

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rc));
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
    context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");


    jettyServer.start();



    primaryStage.show();
   }
}
```

Here's the REST controller code:

```
@Path("stagecontrol")
public class StageControl {

@Inject
private Stage primaryStage;

public StageControl() {

}

@GET
@Path("start")
public Response start() {
    Platform.runLater(() ->primaryStage.setIconified(false));
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@GET
@Path("stop")
public Response stop() {
    Platform.runLater(() ->primaryStage.setIconified(true));
    return Response.ok().build();
}
}
```

When I make a call to /stagecontrol/stop, the application iconifies; when I make a call to /stagecontrol/start, nothing happens.  Is there something about setIconified?

Comment: Works fine for me. Just tested on Mac. When I hit the stop endpoint, the window iconifies into my tray

Comment: Did it restore when you hit the start endpoint?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of the question. But yeah, just tested it and it does restore